# Google Clound Messaging: is Registration ID tied to an app or a device?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to integrate Google Cloud Messaging into my Android app.  I can't tell from the docs whether a registration id is tied to a device or to an app.  It's seems from the docs that it's tied to an app:

> Registration ID: An ID issued by the GCM servers to the Android
>   application that allows it to receive messages. Once the Android
>   application has the registration ID, it sends it to the 3rd-party
>   application server, which uses it to identify each device that has
>   registered to receive messages for a given Android application. In
>   other words, **a registration ID is tied to a particular Android
>   application running **on a particular device****.

It does say "on a particular device".  Does that means I'd need to store a separate registration id in my database for each device the user owns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both.

Just as the documentation you quoted states, the registration ID is tied to your application running on a *particular* device.

GCM sends notifications based on the registration ID alone, so if it were associated with a user, all the user's devices would receive the notifications. This could be a waste, if your app isn't installed on all the user's devices, or it could be a security issue, for example if the user shares a device with someone else, who might receive different notifications from the user who owns the device. I might have a social networking app installed on my phone and my tablets, but the tablets actually have different users (wife or kids). Their notifications should only be sent to the devices where they are logged in, regardless of who owns the device or installed the app.

Short answer: Yes, you need to store a separate registration ID for each device a particular user uses with your app.

Per comment by the original poster, GCM now offers [per-user notifications](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/notifications.html).

Comment: Thanks.  How would you identify the device id?

Comment: The notification itself is handled by the app, right, so unless the app is installed on a device, there won't be a notification.  So, does it really hurt to send the message to all devices?

Comment: The mapping from regId  to a particular device is held by Google. You can't address a device on its own, you can only send a message addressed by regId, which will trigger the receiver on a unique app/device combination.

Comment: It's a waste of resources. I have >20 devices, many android users will have two or three. That's twice the traffic necessary. But that's beside the point -- if google notified devices by user rather than individually, your server and app would have to handle device-specific messages. As implemented, all you need to do is register each device.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I just came across User Notifications, seems to be a new feature: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/notifications.html

Comment: Great find, I amended the answer.

Comment: @323go Without user notifications however, so, would I be getting a different registrationid for each device the user uses?  So I'd need a cross reference table of user id/registration id in my DB, rather than just adding a registrationid column in my Users table, right? I.E., this line here regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID) will get me a different id for each device (same app)?

Comment: Correct. You'll need to have a secondary table (*user, *registrationId)